# VS 2010: Value of type 'System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl' cannot be converted to 'System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlTableRow'

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012

So apparently this error is a known bug in VS 2012, when you try to set a  to runat="server", that contains a  or  element.

Well I'm actually using VS 2010, (though IT did install 2012 last night, and rumors persist that it will trigger this in 2010 as well) and the table elements in question don't have the thead or tbody elements that are supposedly causing this error. But they do have the runat="server" attribute and colgroup elements.

So is this related to the installation of VS 2012? And if so, is there a hotfix for this?

UPDATE:
Removing the colgroup elements seems to resolve this. Even still, this is pretty irritating.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Applying this patch has worked for me: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36359

Obs. I'm using Windows 7 x64, with both VS2010 and VS2012 installed.

Comment: This patch worked for me too. It seems that if a <table> is nested under a <td>, the runat="server" attribute leads to an error.

Answer (score 3):

Had this problem after upgrading to VS 2012 with a `<table run="server"...>` that contained a `<tbody>` element. Removing the `<tbody>` resolved the build error for me.