# How to set source of video tag in code behind?

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, html5-video

I use this code in ASPX file:

```
 <video width="320" height="240" autoplay="autoplay">
    <source id="videoSrc" runat="server"  type="video/mp4"/>
    Your browser does not support the video tag.
 </video>
```

but when I use this code in code behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    videoSrc.Src= "UploadMovies/"+Request.QueryString["id"]+"/high.mp4";
}
```

and call my page as *`myPage.aspx?id=1`* I get this error on `<source>`:

> The base class includes the field 'videoSrc', but its type (System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlSource) is not compatible with the type of control (System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are few things you could do here.

First is to get rid of `<source>` completely and use `src` attribute. You need to make `video` a server-side control, but that won't cause the error:

```
<video width="320" height="240" autoplay="autoplay" id="video" runat="server">
</video>

video.Attributes["src"] = "UploadMovies/"+Request.QueryString["id"]+"/high.mp4";
```

Another thing is to have a code behind function that will give you a video link:

```
<video width="320" height="240" autoplay="autoplay">
    <source type="video/mp4" src='<%= GetVideoLink() %>'/>
</video>

protected string GetVideoLink()
{
    return "UploadMovies/"+Request.QueryString["id"]+"/high.mp4";
}
```

Here you can also use parameters and have several `<source>` tags to support fallback.

As to the error you are seeing, it is not obvious why would that be happening. HtmlSource is the right type of control for `source` tag, it is not clear why ASP.NET decides to treat it as generic html control instead. You can try [this workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19632649/728795) though.

Answer (score 2):

Not specifying the source attribute may lead to incompatibility issues on some browsers (e.g: Safari. See https://github.com/mediaelement/mediaelement/issues/486).

Not a big deal, though. `Source` inner tags can be created from server side:

```
// Assuming we have runat="server" video tag in the markup side, with ID=vid:
// We could cast it as HtmlGenericControl. e.g: in a ItemDataBound event of a Repeater

// Now create the source tag    
HtmlGenericControl source1 = new HtmlGenericControl("source");

source1.Attributes["src"] = "your_video_url";
source1.Attributes["type"] = "video/mp4";

// We can also add additional sources:
HtmlGenericControl source2 = new HtmlGenericControl("source");
source2.Attributes["src"] = "your_video_second_url";
source2.Attributes["type"] = "video/webm";

// Now add the sources as child controls of the video control
vid.Controls.Add(source1);
vid.Controls.Add(source2);
```