# (System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button) is not compatible with the type of control (System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlButton)

Tags: c#

When I run the application works on Visual Studio it works perfectly but when I upload it on the server I get an error of

```
The base class includes the field 'hiddenButton', but its type(System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button) is not compatible with the type of control (System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlButton).
```

For Button I Used:

```
<button id="hiddenButton" runat="server" onserverclick="btnClick_Click" style="display:none;" ></button>
```

C# code is:

```
   protected void btnClick_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        DownloadAsPDF();
    }

    public void DownloadAsPDF()
    {
```

Comment: so what's your question?  The error seems pretty straight forward.

Comment: Have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19502307/asp-net-error-type-is-not-compatible-with-the-type-of-control

Comment: @ sous 2817 It runs in Visual Studio but not on the server.

Comment: @LiverpoolCoder didn't work, already tried that

Comment: What line of code actually throws the error? You didn't include that in your question. You don't have an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @mason the line which has the button

<button id="hiddenButton" runat="server" onserverclick="btnClick_Click"       style="display:none;" ></button>

Comment: That line alone will not result in the error you mentioned. Please read over [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Something in your code or the designer file is mismatched. Following the MCVE guidelines will help you narrow down where the issue is.

Comment: <input type="button" ID="submit"  class="btn btn-success" value="Approve" />                   <button id="hiddenButton" runat="server" onserverclick="btnClick_Click" style="display:none;" ></button>

Answer (score 0):

I changed some ASP buttons to HTML buttons:

From `<asp:Button ID="btnAdd" runat="server" UseSubmitBehavior="false" Text="Add" />`

To `<button ID="btnAdd" runat="server" type="button">Add</button>`

This caused the same error you received. The solution was to add the directive 
`using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;` to my code behind (.cs) file.

Apparently changing the ID to something different than the original control would have tipped off the compiler, but I'm not certain about that and didn't want to change my ID, compile everything and then change the ID back to what I originally wanted.

Having said that, changing the ID did get the squiggly error indicator to go away. But in the end I just manually inserted the directive into the code behind and it worked out.
Props to [this article](https://briancaos.wordpress.com/2013/08/07/system-web-ui-htmlcontrols-htmliframe-is-not-compatible-with-the-type-of-control-system-web-ui-htmlcontrols-htmlgenericcontrol/) that provided the insight.

Answer (score 0):

I had to clean my solution for the warning to go away. Build Menu -> Clean Solution.

It happened because I changed the  to  while IIS Express was still running.